# Global 'Last updated' timestamp

Tags: nodes, theming

Is there a way to create and display a global 'Last updated' timestamp that would be displayed on every page? 'Last updated' would include adding and changing any piece of content on the website. I know how to display a similar timestamp for each node but I'd like to be able to display just one per page. Maybe looping through all created nodes and finding the latest date? How would I achieve that? Or is there a better solution - looping through all nodes might be memory-intensive, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by *"Last Updated"* you are only talking about nodes, then yes, you can.

Create a new view for content (using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module), add a block display, do not filter by any content type, but I think that you can keep the "Published" status. Sort by updated time, descendant, set the pager to show only 1 node. And set the display to only show the updated time. That's all.

Comment: I ended up doing a similar thing but with the page preprocessor function